# Is there something similar to FOAF, but for places?

Tags: xml, rdf, ontology

I'd like to embed some information about places in my XML, and am wondering if a standard already exists.

Specifically, I'm looking for an xmlns that 'supports' at least the following information: country, state/province, city.

Comment: This is a good question, but it might be off-topic for StackOverflow, since it's not about a specific programming problem.  However, you might have much better luck with this question on answers.semanticweb.com, where this is on-topic.  There's also a possible StackExchange site (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53218/semantic-web) where this would probably be on-topic, which you may want to keep an eye on in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t recommend any vocabulary resp. URI collection, I just list here what I heard of:

- [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html): "geospatial semantic information"
- [LoC: MARC List for Countries](http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries.html)
- [UN: Geopolitical information](http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/geoinfo/en/): "information about countries and/or regions"
- [GeoSPARQL](http://schemas.opengis.net/geosparql/1.0/geosparql_vocab_all.rdf): "An RDF/OWL vocabulary for representing spatial information"
- [GeoOnion](http://www.w3.org/wiki/GeoOnion): "relate spatial things together based on their distance in metres"
- [Basic Geo (WGS84 lat/long) Vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/): "representing lat(itude), long(itude) and other information about spatially-located things, using WGS84 as a reference datum"
- [GeoRSS](http://georss.org/): "Geographically Encoded Objects for RSS feeds"
- [`geo:` URI](http://geouri.org/): "identifies a physical location in a two- or three-dimensional coordinate reference system in a compact, simple, human-readable, and protocol-independent way"
- [Address Schema](http://schemas.talis.com/2005/address/schema): properties: country name, locality name, postal code, region name, street address, tel, fax

Answer (score 2):

[VCard in RDF](http://www.w3.org/Submission/vcard-rdf/) may be something that you want.

Also you can go to [Linked Open Vocabularies (LOV)](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/index.html) to find out more other vocabs.